# Join two csv files with pandas/python without duplicates

Tags: python, csv, pandas

I would like to concatenate 2 csv files. Each CSV file has the following structure:

File 1

`id,name,category-id,lat,lng
4c29e1c197,Area51,4bf58dd8d,45.44826958,9.144208431
4ede330477,Punto Snai,4bf58dd8d,45.44833354,9.144086353
51efd91d49,Gelateria Cecilia,4bf58dd8d,45.44848931,9.144008735`

File 2

`id,name,category-id,lat,lng
4c29e1c197,Area51,4bf58dd8d,45.44826958,9.144208432
4ede330477,Punto Snai,4bf58dd8d,45.44833354,9.144086353
51efd91d49,Gelateria Cecilia,4bf58dd8d,45.44848931,9.144008735
5748729449,Duomo Di Milano,52e81612bc,45.463898,9.192034`

I got a final csv that look like

Final file

`id,name,category-id,lat,lng
4c29e1c197,Area51,4bf58dd8d,45.44826958,9.144208431
4c29e1c197,Area51,4bf58dd8d,45.44826958,9.144208432
4ede330477,Punto Snai,4bf58dd8d,45.44833354,9.144086353
51efd91d49,Gelateria Cecilia,4bf58dd8d,45.44848931,9.144008735
5748729449,Duomo Di Milano,52e81612bc,45.463898,9.192034`

So I have done this:

```
import pandas as pd

df1=pd.read_csv("file1.csv")
df2=pd.read_csv("file2.csv")

full_df = pd.concat(df1,df2)

full_df = full_df.groupby(['id','category_id','lat','lng']).count()

full_df2 = full_df[['id','category_id']].groupby('id').agg('count')

full_df2.to_csv("final.csv",index=False)
```

I tried to groupby by id, categoy_id, lat and lng, the name could change
After the first groupby I want to groupby again but now by id and category_id because as showed in my example the first row changed in long but that is probably because file2 is an update of file1

I don't understand about groupby because when i tried to print I got just the count value.

Comment: I edited the file @shivsn

Answer (score 4):

One way to solve this problem is to just use df.drop_duplicates() after you have concatenated the two DataFrames. Additionally, drop_duplicates has an argument "keep", which allows you to specify that you want to keep the last occurrence of the duplicates.

```
full_df = pd.concat([df1,df2])
unique_df = full_df.drop_duplicates(keep='last')
```

Check the [documentation](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html) for drop_duplicates if you need further help.

Answer (score 1):

I could resolve this problemen with the next code:

```
import pandas as pd

df1=pd.read_csv("file1.csv")
df2=pd.read_csv("file2.csv")

df_final=pd.concat([df1,df2]).drop_duplicates(subset=['id','category_id','lat','lng']).reset_index(drop=True)
print(df_final.shape)

df_final2=df_final.drop_duplicates(subset=['id','category_id']).reset_index(drop=True)

df_final2.to_csv('final', index=False)
```